# How onCleared works AndroidViewModel [android-architecture-component]

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

i am using AndroidViewModel and returning stream of data be it Observable or LiveData, so far its going well, i see there is a method in ViewModel class, `onCleared()` document says

> This method will be called when this ViewModel is no longer used and
>   will be destroyed.It is useful when ViewModel observes some data and
>   you need to clear this subscription to prevent a leak of this
>   ViewModel.

I have a scenario where i return `Single<ApiResponse>` from retrofit do some `.map()` in `ViewModel` and return response as `Single<ToBeShownOnUiResponse>` i subscribe this in View i.e Fragment.
I add subscriber to `CompositeDisposable` and thereafter clear it `onStop` fragment. When i navigate from LoginActivity(hold signin/signup/passwordreset fragment) to HomeActivity(hold tablayout with other fragments) i dont see the logs written in onCleared() method of ViewModel class. Is something wrong i am doing or i did a complete mess of it.

My query here is that in what way `onCleared()` is helpful to me. What separate code or cleanup i should be writing in it?

Usage:
When i need string resource then i use `AndroidViewModel`(Formatting some api response according to string resource present in xml) and when only api call require i use `ViewModel`.

Comment: you can dispose the disposable in onCleared in your viewmodel. a nice blog if you need the code https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c

Comment: correct, but as per google samples they have written disposable in View(Activity/Fragment) and not in ViewModels

Comment: that can also work what you do is unsubscribe when activity/fragment is destoryed

Answer (score 0):

One example use case of calling `onCleared` is when you use a `ViewModel` for in-app billing. In that case, it is natural to let the BillingClient to persist as long as an activity (In the below example I used `Application`), for example like this:

```
class BillingViewModel(application: Application)
  : AndroidViewModel(application), PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener {

  private lateinit var playStoreBillingClient: BillingClient

  init {
    playStoreBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(application.applicationContext)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .setListener(this).build()
    playStoreBillingClient.startConnection(this)
  }

...

 override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    playStoreBillingClient.endConnection()
}
```